# Android gradle runtimeClasspath equivalent

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The gradle `java` plugin has a `FileCollection` property which contains the runtime classes - `sourcesets.main.runtimeClasspath`.

Is there an equivalent within the `com.android.application` plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've found is that the `destinationDir` property of `applicationVariants` can be appended to the `javaCompile.classpath` property, which will result in a `FileCollection` which contains the dependency classpaths and the compiled classes.

My use case is trying to run a java executable post-compile:

```
afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->
        variant.javaCompile.doLast {
            javaexec {
                classpath += variant.javaCompile.classpath
                classpath += files(variant.javaCompile.destinationDir)
                main = 'com.mydomain.Main'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested on Android Studio 2.1.1 running `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'` and gradle 2.10.

Reference: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Shrinking-Resources

Comment: since `javaCompile` is now deprected, you can use `variant.javaCompileProvider.get().classpath` (kotlin syntax, might be slightly different in groovy). Also note though that this will cause a task dependency on compiling the sourcecode, which is sometimes problematic for code generation. In that case you can add a `doFirst {}` block around setting the classpath.