# Use Android module runtime classpath in JavaExec gradle task

Tags: android, gradle, javaexec-gradle-plugin

I have and Android module which contains a Gradle JavaExec task. When running the JavaExec task, I would like it to use the classpath of the module.
The JavaExec task executes a Kotlin main function which uses some 3rd party library (kotlinpoet). But when running the Gradle task, I'm getting a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` due to kotlinpoet library not being included in the classpath.

I've found similar issues in StackOverflow, and tried many variants for the `classpath` parameter in the `myTask`, but nothing that worked.

Here's is the `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30    
    defaultConfig {
    ...
    }
    buildTypes {
    ...
    }
    compileOptions {
    ...
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

task myTask(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath += (files('build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug', "${android.sdkDirectory}/tools/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.1.3-2.jar", getBuildDir().toString() + "/intermediates/classes/debug"))
    main = 'com.foo.app.home.parser.MainKt'
}

tasks.named('build') { dependsOn('configGeneratorTask') }

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$androidx_core_ktx"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:$kotlinx_serialization_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:$kotlinx_serialization_version"
    implementation 'com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.10.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the classpath from each variant. This should do the trick:

```
afterEvaluate { // needed to make sure all android setup is available
    task myTask(type: JavaExec) {
        // you probably don't even need to set all these paths manually anymore
        classpath += files(
                'build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug',
                "${android.sdkDirectory}/tools/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.1.3-2.jar",
                getBuildDir().toString() + "/intermediates/classes/debug"
        )

        android.applicationVariants.each { variant -> // or libraryVariants
            // add each variant's compiler classpath onto this classpath
            classpath += variant.javaCompileProvider.get().classpath
        }
        // uncomment the line below if you need the android.jar etc
        // classpath += files(android.bootClasspath) 

        // setting main directly is now deprecated. Set it like this:
        mainClass.set('com.foo.app.home.parser.MainKt') 
    }
}
```

Also see this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37268008/3968618